# How to install native library dependencies of RubyGems in flexible ruby runtime

Tags: google-app-engine, rubygems

My project has a few gems that are wrappers for native libraries, like `libmagic`. Is there a way to install those inside a ruby runtime, besides the need to create a full custom app engine runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it:

- Create a Docker config file `gcloud preview app gen-config --custom`
- Add RUN command to docker file e.g. `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmagic-dev exiftool`
- Deploy app: `gcloud preview app deploy`